# How to animate scrolling right automatically like a news ticker?

Tags: php, jquery, animation, scroll

I'm looking for a way the body to animate scrolling right like a news ticker. The only way for me to scroll is to have the `body` with `overflow-x:auto` and `overflow-y:auto`. The width of the body is set so high that it's basically an infinity width.jq

This is what I've done so far:

```css
body {overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:auto;height:10px;width:500000px}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="test">Lorem Khaled Ipsum is a major key to success. The ladies always say Khaled you smell good, I use no cologne. Cocoa butter is the key. I told you all this before, when you have a swimming pool, do not use chlorine, use salt water, the healing, salt water is the healing. I’m up to something. Watch your back, but more importantly when you get out the shower, dry your back, it’s a cold world out there. They key is to have every key, the key to open every door. Surround yourself with angels, positive energy, beautiful people, beautiful souls, clean heart, angel. Bless up. They don’t want us to eat. The weather is amazing, walk with me through the pathway of more success. Take this journey with me, Lion! The key to success is to keep your head above the water, never give up. You see that bamboo behind me though, you see that bamboo? Ain’t nothin’ like bamboo. Bless up. They will try to close the door on you, just open it. To succeed you must believe. When you believe, you will succeed. You see that bamboo behind me though, you see that bamboo? Ain’t nothin’ like bamboo. Bless up.
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite easy. Make a relative div with an absolute in it. Overflow-x the outer and position the inner.

```js
const content = document.getElementById('content');
let pos = 400;
const scroller = function() {
  pos--;
  content.style.left = pos + 'px';
  window.requestAnimationFrame(scroller);
}

scroller();
```

```css
.scroller {
  width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#content {
  width: 1000em;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: no-wrap;
  left: 400px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="scroller">
    <div id="content">Lorem Khaled Ipsum is a major key to success. The ladies always say Khaled you smell good, I use no cologne. Cocoa butter is the key. I told you all this before, when you have a swimming pool, do not use chlorine, use salt water, the healing, salt
      water is the healing. I’m up to something. Watch your back, but more importantly when you get out the shower, dry your back, it’s a cold world out there. They key is to have every key, the key to open every door. Surround yourself with angels, positive
      energy, beautiful people, beautiful souls, clean heart, angel. Bless up. They don’t want us to eat. The weather is amazing, walk with me through the pathway of more success. Take this journey with me, Lion! The key to success is to keep your head
      above the water, never give up. You see that bamboo behind me though, you see that bamboo? Ain’t nothin’ like bamboo. Bless up. They will try to close the door on you, just open it. To succeed you must believe. When you believe, you will succeed.
      You see that bamboo behind me though, you see that bamboo? Ain’t nothin’ like bamboo. Bless up.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Very nice. Is there a way that you can think of to detect the end of the string and start again from the beginning?

Comment: Sure. You can count the characters in it and multiply by fontsize. If the left position is less then that minus the screenwidth, reset pos to screenwidth.

Comment: Not exactly. But you may create an invisible div, use no-wrap and get the pixel width from that.

Comment: Ah yes - that would work. Thanks again, if I could upvote twice I would!

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works great! I'm assuming `POS` is speed of scroll? And how difficult would it be to add a delay? (I.E. delay start of the scroll?)

Comment: pos is the left position. The speed is 1 because of `pos--`. You also could decrease more than 1 to speed up, or less to speed down. I kept simple using integer, but you also can use float. To increase the delay you set the pos much higher at the end or trigger the first call of scroller() with window.setTimeout.